# How can hadoop mapreduce get data input from CSV file?

Tags: csv, hadoop, input, split, mapreduce

I want to implement hadoop mapreduce, and I use the csv file for it's input. So, I want to ask, is there any method that hadoop provide for use to get the value of csv file, or we just do it with Java Split String function?

Thanks all.....

Answer (score 5):

By default Hadoop uses a Text Input reader that feeds the mapper line by line from the input file. The key in the mapper is the number of lines read. Be careful with CSV files though, as single columns/fields can contain a line break. You might want to look for a CSV input reader like this one:

https://github.com/mvallebr/CSVInputFormat/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CSVNLineInputFormat.java

But, you have to split your line in your code.

Comment: You mean that on a field can have an break line, right? But If I use that's CSV input reader that problem can be solved?

Comment: You mean that on a field can have an break line, right? But If I use that's CSV input reader that problem can be solved? and how can I use this class CSV input from the hadoop Driver class?

Comment: Sometimes a column value may have line break, carriage return etc. kind of characters in it. And to use CSV format, just use setInputFormatClass function in the driver class.